# Complex file moving logic in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to get a sense of what the best approach might be for moving files from an SFTP to an Azure Data Lake store when there are complex requirements around where the files need to land. An example would be taking a file from the SFTP, parsing out a piece of data from the filename plus the date and landing it in a specific folder on the Data Lake.

I've been looking around for possible solutions, I've seen that perhaps Logic Apps or Azure Functions may be able to help but wanted to know if there's anything I haven't considered that may be better suited for the job at hand.

Comment: Logic Apps should work for this

Answer (score 1):

Logic Apps would be perfect for such a scenario.

Here are some reasons why:

- There are built-in connectors within Logic Apps for the services you're using: [SFTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sftp/), [Azure Data Lake](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuredatalake/) etc.
- Logic Apps provides rich set of programming constructs (i.e. if, switch, loops) and [functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language#functions) (i.e. concat, subsctring, replace, ) that you can use to modify/manipulate your data in transit before they land at your Data Lake store.
- Whenever built-in features come short for your setup, you can still use Azure Functions to implement your solution in code, and run it as an Action in your Logic App.